# Can I style treeview hierarchy buttons?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I just don't like how these +- buttons (that show or hide child data) look like, outdated in my opinion. I want to change them to some other elements (like simple triangles or images/icons). So change this:

[image]

to something like this:

[image]

I thought that Styles can help, but seems that there are no options to change the look of these buttons. Maybe one reason is that as far as I can judge these buttons depend on the system that is used (for Microsoft they are +-, on Linux probably triangles), so maybe that is why I can't configure them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do that without using themes. It is not such complex but need knowledge to use it.

## Light solution:

Firstly, I am creating 3 images all of size 16 by 16 pixels. That size perfectly fit the separation between lines, but you can change them to what fits better for you.

Secondly, I am changing the default button image using 'element_create' (default is plus minus). This thing is called "indicator", it holds the images for this 'buttons'. Code should be simple then. 'image' is how folders looks like when closed ([image]). 'user1' is when they are opened ([image]). 'user2' is for an item in a folder (not a subfolder). I don't want it to show something, so I am using transparent image of size 1 pixel. Width and Height are to make indicator perfectly fit the image.

I also config the Treeview.Item to make extra space to the left. Not really needed.

Finally, create a treeview. So code is following:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style()

# Images I will use (all have a size of 16 by 16 pixels):
images = {
    "folder_closed": tk.PhotoImage(file="folder1.png"),
    "empty": tk.PhotoImage(file="emptypixel.png"),
    "folder_opened": tk.PhotoImage(file="folder2.png")
}

"""
Treeview structure:
Treeview:   Treeview.field( Treeview.padding( Treeview.treearea))
Treeview.Heading:   Treeheading.cell; Treeheading.border( Treeheading.padding( Treeheading.image; Treeheading.text))
Treeview.Cell:   Treedata.padding( Treeitem.text)
Treeview.Item:   Treeitem.padding( Treeitem.indicator; Treeitem.image; Treeitem.text)
"""

style.element_create("Treeitem.indicator",
                     "image", images["folder_closed"],  # for a folder when it is 'closed'
                     ("user1", images['folder_opened']),  # when folder is opened
                     ("user2", images['empty']),  # for a file in a folder (not subfolder). By default same as folders
                     width=16, height=16)  # mine image sizes



style.configure('Treeview.Item', padding=(5, 0))  # may be omitted


# Create you tree!
treeview = ttk.Treeview(root, show='tree')
```

One disadvandage, that could be useful to fix: This style will be used for all treeview in a file. It is not always what is wanted.

## complex solution:

I am adding custom styling. That is made by adding prefix 'Custom' (can be any name) to the Item and Indicator. That makes an inheritance to the default tree elements. The layout of the "Item" needs to be recreated, as new indicator should be added instead of default one. So the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style()

# Images I will use (all have a size of 16 by 16 pixels):
images = {
    "folder_closed": tk.PhotoImage(file="folder1.png"),
    "empty": tk.PhotoImage(file="emptypixel.png"),
    "folder_opened": tk.PhotoImage(file="folder2.png")
}

# this is used to make extra scape from the icons of folders to the rest of the line.
imageToText_padx = 4

style.element_create("Custom.Treeview.indicator",
                     "image", images["folder_closed"],  # for a folder when it is 'closed'
                     ("user1", images['folder_opened']),  # when folder is opened
                     ("user2", images['empty']),  # for a file in a folder (not subfolder). By default same as folders
                     width=16 + imageToText_padx, height=16, sticky='wns')


style.layout("Custom.Treeview.Item", [
        ("Treeitem.padding", {"sticky": "nswe", "children":
            [
             ("Custom.Treeview.indicator", {"side": "left", "sticky": ""}),
             ("Treeitem.image", {"side": "left", "sticky": ""}),
             ("Treeitem.text", {"side": "left", "sticky": ""})
             ]
         })
    ])

style.configure('Custom.Treeview.Item', padding=(5, 0))  # may be omitted


# Apply the custom style to the treeview and create you tree!
treeview = ttk.Treeview(root, style='Custom.Treeview', show='tree')
```

This can be created in one program:

[image]

I am also increasing the space between the folder icon, and the rest of the line by just increasing 'width' in the "element_create" by some number.

Conclusion: Styles are very powerful, if you know, how to use them. The can really change anything in the look of the widgets. Unfortunately, they are not quite good documented.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to create a custom style that changes these images. I'm not an expert in styles, but [the description on tkdocs.com](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html) should give you hints about how to do it.

You could also search the internet for tkinter styles to see if any of them do what you want. For example, [ttkthemes](https://ttkthemes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/themes.html) has several themes that use different types of images in the tree.

Comment: It is indeed possible! But not documented anywhere... [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOSa2.png)